# How to link multiple tables together into a single query

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am in need of help. I never worked with complex databases, and I don't know how to arrange the tables. I need a table with children names, which is linked to their parents account (did this using `$_POST['children_name']`, etc when submitting the registration form), but now I need to link their schools with their grades (example I am in 8 A grade), then their classes with the individual grade school subjects, and then link marks (like A+ in America) and absences to individual children.

I have no idea on how to do this. I made an example, which is illustrated in the photo below. Could you please help me?

(NOTE THAT THERE ARE 3 TABLES THERE)

[Image](http://s22.postimg.org/mnwzpog5d/bazadate.jpg)

LATER EDIT: 
Fluffeh`s solution, a little bit edited! 
"
I would consider the following structure for your tables.

First, a table for all the schools that the website will have data from.

```
id    schoolname
 1     European College#1
 2     European Colelge#2
```

Then, a table of all the classes that are active in a college.

```
id    Class
 1    8A
 2    8B
 3    8C
```

then a table for the subjects offered by all the schools. You will need an ID and then any other information as needed.

```
    schoolSubject
id  name
1   mathematics
2   geography
    3       physics
    4       geometry
```

Next up a table containing relations between the schools, classes and school subjects.

```
relations
SchoolID   ClassID     SubjectID
1           1               1
1           1               2
1           1               4
```

(so, if my logic is correct, class 8A students from the "European College#1" will study mathematics, geography and geometry)

Lastly, we will need to know which student is  from where.

```
students
id  name        class_id   schoolname_id
1   John Doe     1           1
2   Jane Doe     2           2
```

The last tabe pretty much gives us the ability to have a record of multiple grades for the same student for the same subject - in case a student has to take 
a subject more than once.

```
grades
subjectID   studentID   grade
1           1           B,A,B
1           2           A,B,B
2           1           A,C,C
2           2           B,A,A
```

With this structure in place, what query could I use?

Comment: It sort of sounds like a nice join between the tables. It's not about multiple databases, it's about joining the tables in a query. On that note though, your data in the third table seems to be very annoying to join. You should have eight rows, one for each student, not a single row with comma delimited values in a string.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for quick response! The last table joins the individual grade school subjects to their grades (8A for example). In 8A There will be lets say 30 students, all of which have the same school subjects. I was planning to make that in a separate table...I`m so lost :(

Comment: When looking at your sketch, I'd suggest you start with learning the basics of "database normalisation" (http://bit.ly/NyKgQI) and queries. It's not that difficult to start.

Comment: Hmmmm, give me a few minutes, lets get that structure into place and give you a query that will work.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was not aware that "database normalisation" even exists. I read a lot about table joining, I have above-average knowledge about queries. I need to somehow update all the tables when someone ( of higher rank ) inserts values for grades, etc. The account section of the website works, i know how to do everything else, except for how to arrange the tables, so that i can use them in relation. And I have only 2 weeks left to finish:( ..p.s. My current stage of work is here http://test.didacticmedia.ro

Comment: Well, normalisation will help as soon as your recordsets get larger. As for the inserts: If you use InnoDB, use multiple inserts with transactions.

Comment: PS: I would create 1 Table for all the schools (each name only one time), then 1 for the classes, 1 for "materie" AND one more for the relations of classes to "materie" (currently you have alle the values in one field [like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"])

Comment: Hey dwtm.ts! Thanks ! This is the best idea:) It uses what Fluffeh said, but its more specific to what I have to do! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the following structure for your tables.

Firstly, a table for the subjects offered by the school. You will need an ID and then any other information as needed.

```
schoolSubject
id  name
1   mathematics
2   geography
```

Next up a table containing student information. Again, we have a unique ID, then any info as needed

```
student
id  name
1   John Doe
2   Jane Doe
```

The next table allows what is known as a many to many relationship. basically it means you can have multiple entries for the same subject (as many students can be enrolled in each) and multiple entries for students (as students can be enrolled in multiple subjects).

```
studentEnrolment
subjectID   studentID
1           1
1           2
2           1
```

The last tabe pretty much gives us the ability to have a record of multiple grades for the same student for the same subject - in case a student has to take 
a subject more than once.

```
grades
subjectID   studentID   grade
1           1           B
1           2           A
2           1           A
2           2           B
```

With this stucture in place, you can do a query like the following:

```
select
    subj.name,
    stud.name,
    grad.grade
from
    schoolSubject subj
        join studentEnrolment enr
            on subj.id=enr.subjectID
        join student stud
            on enr.studentID=stud.studentID
        join grades grad
            on subj.subjectID=grad.subjectID
            and stud.id=grad.studentID
```

Comment: Thanks for time! Ok, but one problem remains. I will have multiple schools, with multiple grade levels, everyone of which will have unique school subjects. I need to know which student is from which grade level, which school, and what school subjects he/she studies for his specific grade level :( sorry if i was not explicit from start, and thank you a lot for your time!

Comment: It`s a great idea though, i will try to elaborate my own upon your idea, and if I get it right will post it here! Thanks for all your time!

Comment: Please feel free to an an edit to my answer and post the final solution that you decide to go with. Database design is half art, half science :)

Comment: I will, but first i want to have a correct form for others that have the same problem to use. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I cannot vote your answer up, as i dont yet have 15 rep, but i will set it to the accepted answer after finding the final solution. Thank you for all your time!

Comment: No problems :) Again, make sure that you add an edit to it to show your final solution.

Comment: I added some details to the first question, following your advice ( i did not want to edit your post, in case I was wrong) Can you please check it? Thanks!

Comment: @AcelasiEu It looks okay to me :)

Comment: ok, but what query will i use to connect each student with his class, and the school subjects that he has ( only the subjects that he has) and his grades for each subject? Then I will edit and select your answer. Please! Thanks!

Comment: @AcelasiEu That's where your students table comes into play. That's the link between the tables you made.

Comment: ah, i was so tired, sorry, i worked like 30 hours on a row...i managed to do it. Sorry I deselected your answer as the good one, but i tought that if i let it like that everyone will think the problem is solved. Thanks!